# SQL Group and Calculate Avergares

Tags: sql, sqlite

I made a script that downloads stock prices from a website every several minutes.

I've been trying to make a query that returns the highest bid, lowest ask, average asks and bids for a stock "FAV" at the moment they where downloaded, I tried grouping them by "time". This is what I want:

```
+------------+--------+------------+-------------+---------+---------+
|    date    |  time  | lowest_ask | highest_bid | avg_ask | avg_bid |
+------------+--------+------------+-------------+---------+---------+
```

from a table like this:

```
+-----+------------+-------+------+---------+----------+-------+
| id  |    date    | time  | type | company | quantity | price |
+-----+------------+-------+------+---------+----------+-------+
|   7 | 2017-08-08 | 94827 | ask  | BCQ     |    30000 | 0.4   |
|   8 | 2017-08-08 | 94827 | ask  | BCQ     |    87211 | 0.5   |
|   9 | 2017-08-08 | 94827 | ask  | BCQ     |    10658 | 0.4   |
|  10 | 2017-08-08 | 94827 | ask  | BCQ     |    20000 | 0.39  |
|  15 | 2017-08-08 | 94827 | ask  | FAV     |     2600 | 1.9   |
|  16 | 2017-08-08 | 94827 | ask  | FAV     |     3000 | 1.83  |
|  17 | 2017-08-08 | 94827 | ask  | FAV     |      556 | 1.88  |
|  18 | 2017-08-08 | 94827 | ask  | FAV     |      845 | 1.82  |
|  19 | 2017-08-08 | 94827 | ask  | FAV     |      845 | 1.82  |
|  20 | 2017-08-08 | 94827 | ask  | FAV     |     1249 | 1.9   |
|  21 | 2017-08-08 | 94827 | ask  | FAV     |     4024 | 1.9   |
|  37 | 2017-08-08 | 94827 | bid  | FAV     |    10000 | 1.65  |
|  38 | 2017-08-08 | 94827 | bid  | FAV     |      655 | 1.73  |
|  39 | 2017-08-08 | 94827 | bid  | FAV     |     5000 | 1.7   |
|  40 | 2017-08-08 | 94827 | bid  | FAV     |     2102 | 1.65  |
|  41 | 2017-08-08 | 94827 | bid  | FAV     |      618 | 1.75  |
|  42 | 2017-08-08 | 94827 | bid  | FAV     |    10000 | 1.75  |
|  43 | 2017-08-08 | 94827 | bid  | FAV     |      150 | 1.8   |
|  52 | 2017-08-08 | 94953 | ask  | BCQ     |    30000 | 0.4   |
|  53 | 2017-08-08 | 94953 | ask  | BCQ     |    87211 | 0.4   |
|  54 | 2017-08-08 | 94953 | ask  | BCQ     |    10658 | 0.4   |
|  55 | 2017-08-08 | 94953 | ask  | BCQ     |    20000 | 0.4   |
|  60 | 2017-08-08 | 94953 | ask  | FAV     |     2600 | 1.9   |
|  61 | 2017-08-08 | 94953 | ask  | FAV     |     3000 | 1.83  |
|  62 | 2017-08-08 | 94953 | ask  | FAV     |      556 | 1.88  |
|  63 | 2017-08-08 | 94953 | ask  | FAV     |      845 | 1.82  |
|  64 | 2017-08-08 | 94953 | ask  | FAV     |      845 | 1.82  |
|  65 | 2017-08-08 | 94953 | ask  | FAV     |     1249 | 1.9   |
|  66 | 2017-08-08 | 94953 | ask  | FAV     |     4024 | 1.9   |
|  82 | 2017-08-08 | 94953 | bid  | FAV     |    10000 | 1.65  |
|  83 | 2017-08-08 | 94953 | bid  | FAV     |      655 | 1.73  |
|  84 | 2017-08-08 | 94953 | bid  | FAV     |     5000 | 1.7   |
|  85 | 2017-08-08 | 94953 | bid  | FAV     |     2102 | 1.8   |
|  86 | 2017-08-08 | 94953 | bid  | FAV     |      618 | 1.75  |
|  87 | 2017-08-08 | 94953 | bid  | FAV     |    10000 | 2     |
|  88 | 2017-08-08 | 94953 | bid  | FAV     |      150 | 1.8   |
|  97 | 2017-08-08 | 95053 | ask  | BCQ     |    30000 | 0.45  |
|  98 | 2017-08-08 | 95053 | ask  | BCQ     |    87211 | 0.4   |
|  99 | 2017-08-08 | 95053 | ask  | BCQ     |    10658 | 0.5   |
| 100 | 2017-08-08 | 95053 | ask  | BCQ     |    20000 | 0.4   |
| 105 | 2017-08-08 | 95053 | ask  | FAV     |     2600 | 1.9   |
| 106 | 2017-08-08 | 95053 | ask  | FAV     |     3000 | 1.83  |
| 107 | 2017-08-08 | 95053 | ask  | FAV     |      556 | 1.88  |
| 108 | 2017-08-08 | 95053 | ask  | FAV     |      845 | 1.82  |
| 109 | 2017-08-08 | 95053 | ask  | FAV     |      845 | 1.82  |
| 110 | 2017-08-08 | 95053 | ask  | FAV     |     1249 | 1.9   |
| 111 | 2017-08-08 | 95053 | ask  | FAV     |     4024 | 1.9   |
| 127 | 2017-08-08 | 95053 | bid  | FAV     |    10000 | 1.65  |
| 128 | 2017-08-08 | 95053 | bid  | FAV     |      655 | 1.89  |
| 129 | 2017-08-08 | 95053 | bid  | FAV     |     5000 | 1.7   |
| 130 | 2017-08-08 | 95053 | bid  | FAV     |     2102 | 1.65  |
| 131 | 2017-08-08 | 95053 | bid  | FAV     |      618 | 1.75  |
| 132 | 2017-08-08 | 95053 | bid  | FAV     |    10000 | 1.95  |
| 133 | 2017-08-08 | 95053 | bid  | FAV     |      150 | 1.8   |
+-----+------------+-------+------+---------+----------+-------+
```

However this query doesn't provide the expected results, it just gives the averages per day, not by time of the day:

```
select 
    date,
    time,
    (select min(price) from monitor where type = "ask") as lowest_ask,
    (select max(price) from monitor  where type = "bid") as highest_bid,
    (select avg(price) from monitor  where type = "ask") as avg_ask,
    (select avg(price) from monitor  where type = "bid") as avg_bid
from monitor where  date = date("now") and company = "FAV"
group by time
```

Comment: What about adding the date in group by clause as well.

Comment: do you want price by time irrespective of day or including day?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide desired results.  I cannot figure out what this is supposed to mean:  "returns the highest bid, lowest ask, average asks and bids for a stock "FAV" at the moment they where downloaded".

Answer (score 0):

Odd that day's not included in the grouping but... maybe you want to see avg min/max at specific times... irrespective of day?

```
select 
    date,
    time,
    (select min(price), time  from monitor z where type = "ask" and Z.time = m.time GROUP BY time) as lowest_ask,
    (select max(price), time  from monitor  where type = "bid" and Z.time = m.time GROUP BY time) as highest_bid,
    (select avg(price), time  from monitor  where type = "ask" and Z.time = m.time GROUP BY time) as avg_ask,
    (select avg(price), time  from monitor  where type = "bid" and Z.time = m.time GROUP BY time) as avg_bid
from monitor m 
where  date = date("now") and company = "FAV"
group by time
```

though using window functions there may be a cleaner approach...

If you really needed date/time in the group by.. here's the window function approach:

```
select 
    date,
    time,
    min(case when type = 'ask' then price end) over (partition by date,time) as lowest_Ask
    max(case when type = 'bid' then price end) over (partition by date,time) as higest_Bid
    avg(case when type = 'ask' then price end) over (partition by date,time)  as avg_ask,
    avg(case when type = 'bid' then price end) over (partition by date,time)  as avg_bid
from monitor 
where  date = date("now") and company = "FAV"
group by date, time
```

Answer (score 0):

my first guess for not getting correct result is use of subqueries, since first aggregate function is being calculated and then group by "time" happens.can you try this:

```
select 
  date,
  time,
  min(price) as lowest_ask,

  from monitor where  date = date("now") and company = "FAV"
  group by time
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the date/time component.  Assuming your intention is for the values to be on the same day:

```
select date, time,
       (select min(m2.price) from monitor m2 where m2.company = m.company and m2.type = 'ask' and m2.date = m.date and m2.time <= m.time) as lowest_ask,
       (select max(m2.price) from monitor m2 where m2.company = m.company and m2.type = 'bid' and m2.date = m.date and m2.time <= m.time) as highest_bid,
       (select avg(m2.price) from monitor m2 where m2.company = m.company and m2.type = 'ask' and m2.date = m.date and m2.time <= m.time) as avg_ask,
       (select avg(m2.price) from monitor m2 where m2.company = m.company and m2.type = 'bid' and m2.date = m.date and m2.time <= m.time) as avg_bid
from monitor m
where m.date = date("now") and m.company = 'FAV';
```